# Delete operation mysql cluster

Tags: mysql, ndbcluster, mysql-cluster

I am trying to delete some entries from table on a cluster and I get this error

ERROR 1297 (HY000): Got temporary error 233 'Out of operation records in transaction coordinator (increase MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations)' from NDBCLUSTER

I have increased **MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations=1000000**

but I still get this error

I never get this error when selecting or inserting.

Comment: Run: "ndb_config --type ndbd --query 'Nodeid,host,MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations' -f' ' -r '\n'" to double check if your config change applied to data node. And approximately how many rows your query is deleting?

Comment: I have found the problem  I was deleting about 500k records at once, So using LIMIT solved the problem

Comment: Hmm have you restarted whole cluster including Management data and SQl nodes.